# How to I get the timestamp of a max value when grouping by time with InfluxDb

Tags: influxdb

I would like to know when a value peaks everyday of a week.

If I do something like this:

```
select time, max("temperature") from "water_temperatures" GROUP BY time(1d)
```

I get a list of  measurement like this:

```
time                 temperature
----------           -------------
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z 95
2018-01-02T00:00:00Z 97
2018-01-03T00:00:00Z 102
2018-01-04T00:00:00Z 88
2018-01-05T00:00:00Z 94
2018-01-06T00:00:00Z 81
2018-01-07T00:00:00Z 71
2018-01-08T00:00:00Z 98
2018-01-09T00:00:00Z 127
2018-01-10T00:00:00Z 126
```

The timestamp of each records corresponds to the beginning of the range and not the time when the event occurs.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT max("temperature") FROM "water_temperatures WHERE time > now() - 30d
```

That should return a single value that is the max temp, along with its timestamp.

Hope that helps!

dg

Comment: Thanks Davidgs, but what I want to have is the time of the day that I have a max peak for every day of the week. One timestamp + value for every day.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not yet supported as of InfluxDB 1.4. Here the corresponding issue on github: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5926.